# Dell XPS 13 7390 hangs frequently

Tags: 22.04, kde

I have been experiencing random hangs. Switched to Plasma Wayland as suggested in another post. Made no difference.

Any more ideas to try?

Here is the log I see on the console before I have to power cycle the laptop.
Sorry, there might be some errors due to Google Lens text conversion.

```
0626.715736) #CPI Error: No Installed handler for fixed event - PowerButton (2), disabling (20221020/evevent-255)

[8628.291205) nve nvneb: Device not ready: aborting reset, CST-O

8628.3112271 1/0 error, dev nyseont, sector 148753185 op 0x1: (MRITE) flags 0x000 phys seg i prio class 2

0628.3112331 1/0 error, dev nvmeoni, sector 0 op 0x11 (HRITE) fings 000 phys seg 0 pria class 2

0628.311235) I/O error, dev nvmont, sector 559182080 op 0x1: (WRITE) Flags Ox800 phys seg i 0628.3112481 EXT4-fs error (device de-0): ext4 get inode_loc noinmem: 4682: Inode #277901761 block 111149269: com QuotaManager 10: unable to read itable block

prio cless 2

[6628.311260) Buffer 1/0 error on device de-0, Ingical block 5507050 0628.311264) Buffer 1/0 error on device dm-0, logical block 6604456

0628.311277) Buffer 1/0 error on device de-0, logical block 65051705

8628.311279) Buffer 1/0 error on device de-0, logical block 65051706 8628.311294) Buffer L/D error on device de-0, logical block 65051699

8628.311285) Buffer 1/0 error on device dm-0, logical block 65051700

[8629.311296) Buffer 1/0 error on device de-0, logical block 44819936 8629.311307] Buffer 1/0 error on device de-0, logical block 6196766

8628.311311) Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 19516310 8628.311319) Buffer 1/0 error on device de-0, logical block 36426160

18628.311475) Aborting Journal on device do-0-8.

8629.3114931 EXT4-fs (de-0): Delayed block allocation failed for inode 23344109 at logical offset 75 with max blocks 2 with error 30 8628.311495) EXT4-fs error (device da-0): ext4 Journal check start 183: comm kworker/u16:0: Detected aborted Journal

0628.311512) EXT4-fs (da-0): This should not happen!! Date will be lost

18628.311512)

0620.311513) EXT4-fs error (device de-0) in ext4 doritepages:2990: Journal has aborted 18628.311585) EXT4-fs error (device ds-0) in ext4 reserve Inode rite:5911: Journal has aborted

15628.311587) EXT4-fs error (device de-0): ext4.Journal.check_start:83: com ratmain Q:Reg: Detected aborted Journal

10628,3116011 EXT4-fs error (device de-0): ext4 dirty_Inode:6115: inode #22973637: com ThreadPoolFareg: work inode dirty error [8628.311624) Buffer 1/0 error on dev da-0, logical block 0, lost sync page urite

8628.311637) EXT4-fs error (device de-0) in ext4 dirty inode:6116: Journal has aborted 18628.311655) EXT4-fs (da-0): 1/0 error while writing superblock

6628.3116711 EXT4-fs error (device de-0) in ext4 free Inode:362: Journal has aborted

16628.311571) Buffer 1/0 error on dev do-0, logical block 59001600, lost sync page arite I 6620.311702] EXT4-fs error (device de-0) in ext4 evict inode:332: Journal has aborted

I 8628.311707) Buffer 1/0 error on dev de-0, logical block 0, lost sync page urite 10628.3117153 2802: 1/0 error when updating Journal superblock for dm-0-8.

8628.311733) EXT4-fs (do-0): 1/0 error shile writing superblock

10628.311734 EXT4-fs error (device de-0) in ext4 new inode:1135: Journal has aborted 18626.311759) EXT4-fs (do-0): previous I/O error to superblock detected

8628.311838) Buffer 1/0 error on dev de-0, logical block 0, lost sync page arite

10628.311063) EXT4-fs (da-0): 1/0 error shile writing superblock

8628.311876) EXT4-fs (da-0): Rescunting filesystem read-only

8628.3118891 EXT4-fs (do-0): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents potential data loss! (inode 22940312, error -50) 16628.31139251 EXT4-fs (da-0): failed to convert unuritten extents to uritten extents potential data loss! (inode 22945474, error-30)

16628.311954) EXT4-fs (da-0): failed to convert unwritten extents to uritten extents potential data loss! (inode 23724696, error -30) 8620.312000) Buffer 1/0 error on dev de-0, logical block 0, lost sync page write

0628.3120951 Buffer 1/0 error on dev de-0, logical block 0, lost sync page write [6620.312006) Buffer I/O error on dev de-0, logical block 0, lost sync page arite

8628.312119) Buffer 1/0 error on dev de-0, logical block 0, lost sync page arite

10628.312168) Buffer 1/0 error on dev da-0, logical block 0, lost sync page write 10620.312206) Buffer 1/0 error on dev do-0, logical block 0, lost sync page write

Message from syslogdedk-xps at Aug 23 10:44:33... kernel: (0620.211809) EXT4-fs (ds-0): failed to convert unuritten extents to written extents potential date loss (inode 22940312, error -30)

Message from syslogdeck-ps at Aug 23 10:44:33... kernel: 8620.911925) EXT4-fs (da-0): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents- potential date loss! (inode 22943474, error -30)

Message from syslogdeck-ups at Aug 23 10:44:33... kernel: [ 6628.911954) EXT4-fs (da-0): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents potential date loss (Inode 23724696, error -30)
```

[image]

Comment: You have I/O errors; ie. hardware problems..  You can't expect an OS to perform well when there are hardware problems, read the messages & deal with them.. ie. look at and explore your hardware problems.  I'd start with exploring drive health (ie. using the SMART capabilities of your drives), also check RAM (*RAM problems can show in many ways & it's easy to test*), PSU (*good components misbehave when fed bad power*) etc...   FYI:  I/O = Input/Output errors..